# how to order by in rails with priority conditional in attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

example i have a list of users

```
id           name         role

1            join         member
2            cathy        sale
3            mark         admin
4            orthor       member
5            Sy           admin
```

i want to order by role asc with priority when role= 'member'

result:

```
 id           name         role

1            join         member
4            orthor       member
3            mark         admin
5            Sy           admin
2            cathy        sale
```

how to order by this in rails??

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table order by (case when role= 'member' then 0 else 1 end), role

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,name,role
FROM (
    SELECT *, (Case when role='member' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as order_role
    FROM your_table
)
ORDER BY order_role,role ASC
```